ASP.NET Core transfer of authorization token for api
Everything was fine until I realized that my HttpClientContext is a Singleton.
Then I registered it as Scoped and faced the problem of passing authorization token.
My whole project is based on working with api. Each user has his own api login, by which he receives a token that lives for one hour. Ofc each request needs a token.
And as I understand my scope for HttpContext is one request. So for the next request the token is already lost.
What were my ideas? Save the token in the cache for each user. But before each request I have to check if the token is there and set it.
.AddSingleton<INativeHttpClient, WindowsHttpClient>(provider =>
{
   var networkMonitor = provider.GetRequiredService<INetworkManager>();
   return new WindowsHttpClient(networkMonitor);
})
.AddScoped<ITransportHttpClientContext, TransportHttpClientContext>(provider =>
{
   var httpClient = provider.GetRequiredService<INativeHttpClient>();
   return new TransportHttpClientContext(httpClient);
})

Here is my HttpClientContext class
public class TransportHttpClientContext(INativeHttpClient httpClient)
   : HttpClientContext(httpClient), ITransportHttpClientContext
{
   private const string _transportUrl = "https://";
   private string ServerUrl { get; set; } = _transportUrl;


   private string ApiAuthorizationToken { get; set; } = string.Empty;


   public override Uri GetBaseUri() => new(ServerUrl);


   protected override void AddHeaders(HttpRequestHeaders headers)
   {
       headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ApiAuthorizationToken);
   }

 public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string apiLogin)
    {
        var transportTokenEndpoint = new PostAccessTokenApiEndpoint(apiLogin);
        var tokenResponseDto = await RunEndpoint(transportTokenEndpoint).ConfigureAwait(false);
        ApiAuthorizationToken = tokenResponseDto.Token;
        return tokenResponseDto.Token;
    }

Let's say here's my HomeController entry point, the first thing I do is request a token and it's set right into the context.
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
   if (User.Identity is not { IsAuthenticated: true }) return View();
  
   var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
   if (user?.ApiLogin is null) return View();


   await authService.GetAccessTokenAsync(user.ApiLogin);
   await organizationService.GetOrganizationsAsync();
      
   return await LoadHomeController();
}

and then when I make the second request GetOrganizationsAsync(), the token is no longer saved.
How do I properly organize the transfer and storage of the token?
I'm trying to learn how to store and transmit an authorization token.
